# Dinero Multiply() is not a function error inside cart.totalPrice

Tags: javascript

First time I use Dinerojs. I use it inside my shoppingcart which is pure js file.
I'm including part of the code that I think is relevant here but if you need me to post more code, I will be append my question.

My shopping cart code is simple - it's a svelte store:

```
let cartStore = writable({
        items: [],
        totalPrice: 0,
        totalItems : 0
    })
```

and I add items to the shopping cart using the following code :

```
cartStore.update(cartStore => {
                    cartStore.items.push({
                        product: product,
                        totalPrice: product.price,
                        quantity: 1
                    })
```

To compute the item totalPrice I'm trying to multiply item.totalPrice by quantity:

```
updatedCartStore.items.forEach(item => {
            item.totalPrice =  item.product.price * item.quantity;
        });
```

Now this code works before I added Dinerojs to my package.json and attempted to use DineroJS. When I tried to use the Dinero object, I ran into issues which I will explain shortly.

I changed my totalPrice to this:

```
let cartStore = writable({
        items: [],
        totalPrice: Dinero({amount : 0, currency : "USD"}),  // >>>>changed this to include Dinero
        totalItems : 0
    })
```

and when I tried to multiply item.product.price by item.quantity...I got an error that I need to provide an integer, console.log is showing totalPrice as NAN. this is my code:

```
updatedCartStore.items.forEach(item => {
                item.totalPrice = Dinero({ amount : item.product.price}).multiply(item.quantity);
            });
```

I also tried the following which gave me the error "multiply is not a function" :

```
updatedCartStore.items.forEach(item => {
                item.totalPrice =  item.product.price.multiply(item.quantity);
            });
```

So, my question is how to calculate item.totalPrice using Dinero().multiply() ? I need to multiply item.product.price by item.quantity but using Dinero.JS. What is the right way to accomplish this?

Update 1:
Mybe I added Dinero to my front wrong:
My front is this:

```
<ProductCard name ="dinerojs" description="to test using dinerojs" price ={Dinero({amount :40 , currency:"USD" }).toFormat()} options="false" />
```

Mybe toFormat() causes the number to convert to something else?

Comment: By `integral` I'm guessing you mean `integer`. The `amount` must be an integer, so error is probably from `item.product.price`, which is likely not an integer

Comment: You're correct. Integer not integral. Console.log is showing totalPrice as NaN.

Comment: based on your question, I believe `item.product.price` is a decimal number, like `4.99`. It may also be a string, but it will be converted.  Use `item.product.price * 100`, or perhaps `Math.floor(item.product.price * 100)`

Comment: Yes. I'm testing using a  0.40  but when I do this (item.product.price * 100) , the error persist "you must provide an integer"?

Comment: You got me to think about it in a different way. I added Dinero({amount : 40, currency : "USD"}).multiply(item.quantity) and it worked. So maybe the item.product.price is not a Nan. I edited my question and added how I entered the price on the front with toFormat(). I believe that is the issue.

Comment: you just need to make sure `item.product.price` is an integer

Comment: Thanks. I will have to read their document and figure out what toFormat() does

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dinero requires the "amount" to be an integer value. It tracks monetary trasactions in "cents", not "dollars"  (as they call, "Minor Currency", since it supports multiple currencies)

Depending on the currency, you may need to act differently, but the default number of decimal places is 2, so as long as you don't change that, you just need to convert `item.product.price` to an integer:

```
updatedCartStore.items.forEach(item => {
                item.totalPrice = Dinero({ amount : item.product.price * 100}).multiply(item.quantity);
            });
```

Just keep in mind, if you switch to Yen or Peruvian Pesos or something, you may need to adjust things.

Comment: Thank you for your help but error persist ....Dinero needs an integer

Comment: then what value does `item.product.price` have?

Comment: `Number.isInteger( 0.40 * 100)`  gives `true`

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. It's giving me "Nan"....because on the front, I added the price using   price ={Dinero({amount :40 , currency:"USD" }).toFormat()}....I'll have to read what toFormat() does as I think it is causing the number to be displayed and I need to convert it back to ineger or something.